# How to convert SQL Server date stored as binary(4)

Tags: sql-server, date-conversion

I've got an old SQL Server database where date was encoded as `binary(4)`. Values stored in the database look like this:

```
0xC3485749
0xC349023E
0xC3490300
0xC3492838
0xC349185F
0xC3491C2F
0xC349003F
0xC3491B4D
```

For many of them I know the actual dates these values correspond to, e.g. `0xC3485749` is 24.04.1996; `0xC349023E` is 22.05.2000.

Now I need to export the database to MS Access. I tried various attempts to convert binary(4) to human readable forms with  CONVERT, e.g.:

```
CONVERT(date, myvariable, 104)
```

but it ended up with an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: I can't immediately see any logic to the examples you've given, so I'm not surprised SQL Server can't. Assuming you understand them, could you click [edit] under the question and give the steps that you'd use to decode them by hand?

Answer (score 1):

Those binary strings don't seem to be encoding text - 0xC3 isn't even a printable character in most encodings.

The most likely meaning is a numeric value representing some "epoch time" - the number of seconds/minutes/etc since some fixed point. But from the two examples given, it's not clear what unit that would be - the difference is 43765, but the difference between those dates is 1487 days *or* 35688 hours *or* 2141280 minutes *or* 128476800 seconds.

If you can find any source code relating to inserting or retrieving them, you could try reverse-engineering what that is doing.

If not, you'll need to do some investigation. I would suggest getting as many known values as you can, and putting them into a spreadsheet:

- Convert the hexadecimal number value to decimal.
- Put the values in order, and make sure the order of known dates matches their numeric order - if it doesn't, my guess is wrong.
- Find the Unix timestamp (number of seconds since midnight 1970-01-01 UTC) for the known dates.
- Work out the difference between pairs of dates, in both the mystery format and the Unix timestamps.
- Try to find a pattern...